# DataSet used by ReportViewer doesn't use credentials from ConnectionString in App.Config

Tags: c#, sql-server, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a Windows Forms app written in C#, and part of the app has a Reporting form using RDLC reports and a ReportViewer control.

In order to create the reports, for each report I first created a DataSet and added a TableAdapter to the DataSet.  I used the TableAdapter wizard to specify the query for the report, and I selected a ConnectionString that was already defined in App.Config and is used elsewhere in the application.

Everything works fine on my development box, but when I move the app to production where the database password isn't the same as my dev box, the reports all fail to run with the exception that the 'sa' password is invalid.

Now, the password is set properly in the ConnectionString in app.config in production.  I use this same ConnectionString everywhere else in the app, including to log in, so I know that the sa password is set properly.

It seems to me that when I add a TableAdapter to a DataSet using the wizard, and it asked me to choose a connection (which I chose the existing connection that was already in app.config and is used elsewhere in the app), it must be storing it somewhere and not always reading it from app.config.  Or am I misunderstanding something?

I just want each DataSet with its TableAdapter to be able to use the connection string from app.config, which includes the username and password.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked around this by doing the following before calling the Fill method on the TableAdapter...

```
this.EMPLOYEETableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString =
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MCLabor"].ToString();
```

This works.  It's kind of lame though, and it definitely proves that when you create the TableAdapter using the wizard, and you select an existing connection from App.Config (from the Connections drop down box in the wizard), it doesn't actually load that connection string from app.config at runtime.  Does anyone know why, or what the real way to handle this is?  I don't like having to manually set the connection string for every TableAdapter for every DataSet for every report.